# Question on wxWidgets plus GTK+ plus Cairo in an embedded application

Tags: wxwidgets

we are using wxWidgets with GTK+ along with Cairo.  We are seeing poor performance in rendering of screens. Could wxWidgets be the cause?

Comment: did you profile you code? what GTK+/Cairo version do you use? what wx version? what OS? how did you configure wx? is any of wx samples work the same?

Comment: Could the graphics card not properly be configured?

Comment: • Hardware details: PXA270 (ARMV Architecture) with on-chip graphics controller which operates on 512 MHz processor speed and has 64 MB RAM. There is no FPU/GPU.
• Linux kernel version: V2.6.35.9
• Our stack is wxWidgets (V3.0.4) -> GTK+2 (V2.24.32) -> Pango (V1.3.0) -> Cairo (V1.14.12) -> XFbdev (X  server)
• For example, when calling wxMessageBox,
o First, background of message box is drawn
o After noticeable delay, the text and icon are drawn in the message box.
o When click on "OK" button, message box disappears immediately

Comment: In my opinion, that is quite an an old architecture to run wxWidgets 3.0.4. Check https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/page_port.html and wxX11